# Xamarin.Forms need WrapLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm struggling to figure out how to wrap my listview items horizontally and fill up available space within my listview.

So far, the items within my list view do not wrap.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpacing="3" Grid.ColumnSpacing="3" BackgroundColor="Silver">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeIds}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEmployeeId}"
              BackgroundColor="Black" >
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <ViewCell>
            <ViewCell.View>
              <customcontrols:WrapLayoutOld Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Text="{Binding Value}" TextColor="Yellow" XAlign="Start" />
              </customcontrols:WrapLayoutOld>
            </ViewCell.View>
          </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
  </Grid>
```

**WrapLayout:**

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Custom.Controls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// New WrapLayout
    /// </summary>
    /// <author>Jason Smith</author>
    public class WrapLayout : Layout<View>
    {
        Dictionary<View, SizeRequest> layoutCache = new Dictionary<View, SizeRequest>();

        /// <summary>
        /// Backing Storage for the Spacing property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty SpacingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<WrapLayout, double>(w => w.Spacing, 5,
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayout)bindable).layoutCache.Clear());

        /// <summary>
        /// Spacing added between elements (both directions)
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The spacing.</value>
        public double Spacing
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(SpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SpacingProperty, value); }
        }

        public WrapLayout()
        {
            VerticalOptions = HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
        }

        protected override void OnChildMeasureInvalidated()
        {
            base.OnChildMeasureInvalidated();
            layoutCache.Clear();
        }

        protected override SizeRequest OnSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {

            double lastX;
            double lastY;
            var layout = NaiveLayout(widthConstraint, heightConstraint, out lastX, out lastY);

            return new SizeRequest(new Size(lastX, lastY));
        }

        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            double lastX, lastY;
            var layout = NaiveLayout(width, height, out lastX, out lastY);

            foreach (var t in layout)
            {
                var offset = (int)((width - t.Last().Item2.Right) / 2);
                foreach (var dingus in t)
                {
                    var location = new Rectangle(dingus.Item2.X + x + offset, dingus.Item2.Y + y, dingus.Item2.Width, dingus.Item2.Height);
                    LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(dingus.Item1, location);
                }
            }
        }

        private List<List<Tuple<View, Rectangle>>> NaiveLayout(double width, double height, out double lastX, out double lastY)
        {
            double startX = 0;
            double startY = 0;
            double right = width;
            double nextY = 0;

            lastX = 0;
            lastY = 0;

            var result = new List<List<Tuple<View, Rectangle>>>();
            var currentList = new List<Tuple<View, Rectangle>>();

            foreach (var child in Children)
            {
                SizeRequest sizeRequest;
                if (!layoutCache.TryGetValue(child, out sizeRequest))
                {
                    layoutCache[child] = sizeRequest = child.GetSizeRequest(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity);
                }

                var paddedWidth = sizeRequest.Request.Width + Spacing;
                var paddedHeight = sizeRequest.Request.Height + Spacing;

                if (startX + paddedWidth > right)
                {
                    startX = 0;
                    startY += nextY;

                    if (currentList.Count > 0)
                    {
                        result.Add(currentList);
                        currentList = new List<Tuple<View, Rectangle>>();
                    }
                }

                currentList.Add(new Tuple<View, Rectangle>(child, new Rectangle(startX, startY, sizeRequest.Request.Width, sizeRequest.Request.Height)));

                lastX = Math.Max(lastX, startX + paddedWidth);
                lastY = Math.Max(lastY, startY + paddedHeight);

                nextY = Math.Max(nextY, paddedHeight);
                startX += paddedWidth;
            }
            result.Add(currentList);
            return result;
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Simple Layout panel which performs wrapping on the boundaries.
    /// </summary>
    public class WrapLayoutOld : Layout<View>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Backing Storage for the Orientation property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty OrientationProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<WrapLayoutOld, StackOrientation>(w => w.Orientation, StackOrientation.Vertical,
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayoutOld)bindable).OnSizeChanged());

        /// <summary>
        /// Orientation (Horizontal or Vertical)
        /// </summary>
        public StackOrientation Orientation
        {
            get { return (StackOrientation)GetValue(OrientationProperty); }
            set { SetValue(OrientationProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Backing Storage for the Spacing property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly BindableProperty SpacingProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create<WrapLayoutOld, double>(w => w.Spacing, 6,
                propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((WrapLayoutOld)bindable).OnSizeChanged());

        /// <summary>
        /// Spacing added between elements (both directions)
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The spacing.</value>
        public double Spacing
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(SpacingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SpacingProperty, value); }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the spacing or orientation properties are changed - it forces
        /// the control to go back through a layout pass.
        /// </summary>
        private void OnSizeChanged()
        {
            this.ForceLayout();
        }

        //http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/17961/stacklayout-with-horizontal-orientation-how-to-wrap-vertically#latest
        //      protected override void OnPropertyChanged
        //      (string propertyName = null)
        //      {
        //          base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        //          if ((propertyName == WrapLayout.OrientationProperty.PropertyName) ||
        //              (propertyName == WrapLayout.SpacingProperty.PropertyName)) {
        //              this.OnSizeChanged();
        //          }
        //      }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method is called during the measure pass of a layout cycle to get the desired size of an element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="widthConstraint">The available width for the element to use.</param>
        /// <param name="heightConstraint">The available height for the element to use.</param>
        protected override SizeRequest OnSizeRequest(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            if (WidthRequest > 0)
                widthConstraint = Math.Min(widthConstraint, WidthRequest);
            if (HeightRequest > 0)
                heightConstraint = Math.Min(heightConstraint, HeightRequest);

            double internalWidth = double.IsPositiveInfinity(widthConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, widthConstraint);
            double internalHeight = double.IsPositiveInfinity(heightConstraint) ? double.PositiveInfinity : Math.Max(0, heightConstraint);

            return Orientation == StackOrientation.Vertical
                ? DoVerticalMeasure(internalWidth, internalHeight)
                    : DoHorizontalMeasure(internalWidth, internalHeight);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Does the vertical measure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The vertical measure.</returns>
        /// <param name="widthConstraint">Width constraint.</param>
        /// <param name="heightConstraint">Height constraint.</param>
        private SizeRequest DoVerticalMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            int columnCount = 1;

            double width = 0;
            double height = 0;
            double minWidth = 0;
            double minHeight = 0;
            double heightUsed = 0;

            foreach (var item in Children)
            {
                var size = item.GetSizeRequest(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
                width = Math.Max(width, size.Request.Width);

                var newHeight = height + size.Request.Height + Spacing;
                if (newHeight > heightConstraint)
                {
                    columnCount++;
                    heightUsed = Math.Max(height, heightUsed);
                    height = size.Request.Height;
                }
                else
                    height = newHeight;

                minHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, size.Minimum.Height);
                minWidth = Math.Max(minWidth, size.Minimum.Width);
            }

            if (columnCount > 1)
            {
                height = Math.Max(height, heightUsed);
                width *= columnCount;  // take max width
            }

            return new SizeRequest(new Size(width, height), new Size(minWidth, minHeight));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Does the horizontal measure.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The horizontal measure.</returns>
        /// <param name="widthConstraint">Width constraint.</param>
        /// <param name="heightConstraint">Height constraint.</param>
        private SizeRequest DoHorizontalMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
        {
            int rowCount = 1;

            double width = 0;
            double height = 0;
            double minWidth = 0;
            double minHeight = 0;
            double widthUsed = 0;

            foreach (var item in Children)
            {
                var size = item.GetSizeRequest(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
                height = Math.Max(height, size.Request.Height);

                var newWidth = width + size.Request.Width + Spacing;
                if (newWidth > widthConstraint)
                {
                    rowCount++;
                    widthUsed = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
                    width = size.Request.Width;
                }
                else
                    width = newWidth;

                minHeight = Math.Max(minHeight, size.Minimum.Height);
                minWidth = Math.Max(minWidth, size.Minimum.Width);
            }

            if (rowCount > 1)
            {
                width = Math.Max(width, widthUsed);
                height = (height + Spacing) * rowCount - Spacing; // via MitchMilam 
            }

            return new SizeRequest(new Size(width, height), new Size(minWidth, minHeight));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Positions and sizes the children of a Layout.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="x">A value representing the x coordinate of the child region bounding box.</param>
        /// <param name="y">A value representing the y coordinate of the child region bounding box.</param>
        /// <param name="width">A value representing the width of the child region bounding box.</param>
        /// <param name="height">A value representing the height of the child region bounding box.</param>
        protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
        {
            if (Orientation == StackOrientation.Vertical)
            {
                double colWidth = 0;
                double yPos = y, xPos = x;

                foreach (var child in Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible))
                {
                    var request = child.GetSizeRequest(width, height);

                    double childWidth = request.Request.Width;
                    double childHeight = request.Request.Height;
                    colWidth = Math.Max(colWidth, childWidth);

                    if (yPos + childHeight > height)
                    {
                        yPos = y;
                        xPos += colWidth + Spacing;
                        colWidth = 0;
                    }

                    var region = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, childWidth, childHeight);
                    LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, region);
                    yPos += region.Height + Spacing;
                }
            }
            else {
                double rowHeight = 0;
                double yPos = y, xPos = x;

                foreach (var child in Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible))
                {
                    var request = child.GetSizeRequest(width, height);

                    double childWidth = request.Request.Width;
                    double childHeight = request.Request.Height;
                    rowHeight = Math.Max(rowHeight, childHeight);

                    if (xPos + childWidth > width)
                    {
                        xPos = x;
                        yPos += rowHeight + Spacing;
                        rowHeight = 0;
                    }

                    var region = new Rectangle(xPos, yPos, childWidth, childHeight);
                    LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(child, region);
                    xPos += region.Width + Spacing;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`FlexLayout` has been introduced in Xamarin.Forms 3.0, so if you can upgrade you should definitely use it:

> FlexLayout is similar to the Xamarin.Forms StackLayout in that it can
>   arrange its children horizontally and vertically in a stack. However,
>   the FlexLayout is also capable of wrapping its children if there are
>   too many to fit in a single row or column, and also has many options
>   for orientation, alignment, and adapting to various screen sizes.

[Official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout).

Answer (score 0):

I have this list of images and they wrap correctly using the same class you are using, it may be related to LayoutOptions:

```
WrapLayout container = new WrapLayout
{
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    Padding = 10,
    Spacing = 10
};

Image thumbnail = new Image
{
    HeightRequest = 80,
    WidthRequest = 80,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
    //BackgroundColor = Color.Black
    Source = item.ImageText,
    Aspect = Aspect.AspectFit
};
```